# how to add values for frozen dataclasses during initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have two dataclasses that I need to add dynamicly generated attribute "code: a lower case version of the name" on both of them

for the first one I did

```
@dataclass()
class FirstClass:
    name: str
    code: Optional[str] = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.code = self.name.lower()
```

with init=False I don't need to provide it in the constructor, since it's gonna be generated anyway

however second class is Frozen because I cache its return since it's too big and too expensive to read everytime

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SecondClass:
    name: str
```

is there anyway to add dynamically generated attribute during init and not post_init because frozen dataclasses are read-only

so I want to do something like

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SecondClass:
    name: str
    code: str = name.lower()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use `object.__setattr__` to bypass the fact that the dataclass is frozen:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SecondClass:
    name: str
    code: 'str | None' = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self, ):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'code', self.name.lower())


print(SecondClass('Test'))
```

Another option could be to add a helper class method `new()` which can be used to instantiate a new `SecondClass` object:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SecondClass:
    name: str
    code: 'str | None'

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, name: str):
        return cls(name, name.lower())


print(SecondClass.new('Hello'))
```

Comment: first option is great! exactly what I'm looking for, thanks
in fact do you think if it's more performant that way than self.code = self.name.lower()?

Comment: @brightstar2100 it should actually be slower, at least when I timed it on my machine, it appears that `self.code = ...` is about 2x faster than the `object.__setattr__` approach. however, the benefit is that it does present a work around for frozen dataclasses.

Comment: @brightstar2100 I forgot to add, but if you look at the source code for `dataclasses`, you'll notice that they're using the same approach with `object.__setattr__` for assigning to variables in the generated `__init__` method. So actually, performance wise you shouldn't notice much of a difference between #1 and 2.

Comment: ah, so it's either both these options with the same performance or a custom made init with about double the performance at least on your machine, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @brightstar2100 I did test with a custom init, but had a hard time implementing it for the frozen case. I had to disable the `frozen=True` for the `self.code = ...` approach to work within the init method.

Comment: ah I see, I'll use the first approach then, it was exactly what I'm looking for anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a combination of the first approach with a custom creation function:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SecondClass:
    name: str
    code: Optional[str]


def create_second(name):
    return SecondClass(name, name.lower())


print(create_second('Me'))
```

Result:

```
SecondClass(name='Me', code='me')
```

Comment: seems reasonable enough, guess I was looking for something from within dataclasses itself

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using `@property` - doesn't store `code` in the class but exposes it as an attribute:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SecondClass:
    name: str

    @property
    def code(self):
        return self.name.lower()


print(SecondClass('Me').code)
```

Result:

```
me
```

Comment: for quick I access yes I can see this working, but I'm looking at it mostly to expose an api, so the "code" attribute needs to be able to be returned with the rest of the attributes, thanks for the help tho